# Full height Sidebar -- no matter what I put in there?

Tags: html, css

I am a novice at html/css.

I am trying to make sure I never have a sidebar scroll -- no matter what I put in the sidebar-content-area. I prefer my layout height dimensions as I have them now (i.e. the sidebar is not full page). Is there anyway to keep the content area from overflowing....?

Here is my site (if you click on a building you will see sidebar-content-area populate...I need to put some sort of warning in html, but haven't figured out how to do that yet).

https://googledrive.com/host/0BxTGtYdXPZ8QTmdMQVk3X0hQU28/API_Updated_5_3_13.html

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid scrolling in your sidebar just add

```
#sidebarItem, 
#sidebar-content-area, 
#overview { 
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

to your css. This just hides your scrolling.